# How do I create a reset for my SQL CLR running total function?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a SQL CLR function that performs a running total similar to what's explained here: [SQL Server and fastest running totals using CLR – Updated](http://www.pawlowski.cz/2010/09/sql-server-and-fastest-running-totals-using-clr/)

However, this function only does a running total of all the values in a column. What I'm trying to do is reset the running total so that it goes to 0 whenever there's a transition between field1 (SQL varchar) and field2 (SQL numeric). However, I can't seem to figure out the necessary code to do this. I've tried storing both fields using CallContext, but I keep running into null references. I figured the transition detection would work similarly to the running total calculation, but it doesn't. I've been racking my brain for several hours on this with no luck.

Here's the table that I'm using this function against, the primary key is `REF_NO`:

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USER_TB_TIME_TICKETS] (
    [REF_NO] [dbo].[T_DOC_NO] NOT NULL,
    [REF_DAT] [dbo].[T_DAT_SMALL] NOT NULL,
    [ACT_DAT] [dbo].[T_DAT_SMALL] NOT NULL,
    [USR_ID] [dbo].[T_USR_ID] NOT NULL,
    [CUST_NO] [dbo].[T_CUST_NO] NOT NULL,
    [JOB_NO] [dbo].[USER_TB_T_JOB_NO] NOT NULL,
    [CODE] [dbo].[USER_TB_T_SERV_COD] NOT NULL,
    [HRS_WORKED] [dbo].[USER_TB_T_HOURS] NOT NULL,
    [DESCR] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [MILEAGE] [dbo].[USER_TB_T_MILES] NULL,
    [NOTES] [dbo].[USER_TB_T_NOTE] NULL,
    [BILL_FLG] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [BILL_HRS] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
    [EXCESS_HRS] [decimal](6, 2) NULL,
)`

Here's the SQL scalar CLR function wrapper:

`CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RunningTotalDecimal_15_2_ResetStringNumeric](
    @val [decimal](15, 2), 
    @id [tinyint], 
    @rowNo [int], 
    @nullValue [decimal](15, 2), 
    @field1 [nvarchar](15), 
    @field2 [numeric](18, 0))
RETURNS [decimal](15, 2) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [SqlClrRunningTotals].[RDSAPI.SQLClrRunningTotals.RunningTotals].[RunningTotalDecimalResetStringNumeric]`

And here's the C# code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Storage Structure for holding actual Total and row number for security check.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Totals Data Type</typeparam>
    private struct RtStorage<T> where T : struct
    {
        public T Total;
        public int RowNo;
    }

    private struct StringFieldStorage<T> where T : struct
    {
        public T stringField;    
    }

    private struct NumericFieldStorage<T> where T : struct
    {
        public T numericField;
    }
```

`....Other extraneous class code...`

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Calculates a running totals on Decimal data type based on transistion between a string and numeric field.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="val">Value of current row</param>
    /// <param name="id">ID of the function in single query</param>
    /// <param name="rowNo">Specifies expecter rowNo. It is for security check to ensure correctness of running totals</param>
    /// <param name="nullValue">Value to be used for NULL values</param>
    /// <param name="field1">String field</param>
    /// <param name="field2">Numeric field</param>
    /// <returns>SqlDecimal representing running total</returns>
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
    public static SqlDecimal RunningTotalDecimalResetStringNumeric(SqlDecimal val, SqlByte id, int rowNo, SqlDecimal nullValue, SqlString field1, SqlDecimal field2)
    {
        string dataName = string.Format("MultiSqlRt_{0}", id.IsNull ? 0 : id.Value);
        string field1Name = string.Format("MultiSqlField1_{0}", id.IsNull ? 0 : id.Value);
        string field2Name = string.Format("MultiSqlField2_{0}", id.IsNull ? 0 : id.Value);

        object lastSum = CallContext.GetData(dataName);
        object field1Value = CallContext.GetData(field1Name);
        object field2Value = CallContext.GetData(field2Name);

        var storage = lastSum != null ? (RtStorage<SqlDecimal>)lastSum : new RtStorage<SqlDecimal>();
        storage.RowNo++;

        var stringFieldStorage = field1Value != null ? (StringFieldStorage<SqlString>)field1Value : new StringFieldStorage<SqlString>();
        var numericFieldStorage = field2Value != null ? (NumericFieldStorage<SqlDecimal>)field2Value : new NumericFieldStorage<SqlDecimal>();

        if (storage.RowNo != rowNo)
            throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Rows were processed out of expected order. Expected RowNo: {0}, received RowNo: {1}", storage.RowNo, rowNo));

        if (stringFieldStorage.stringField != field1 || (stringFieldStorage.stringField == field1 && numericFieldStorage.numericField != field2))
        {
            storage.Total = new SqlDecimal(0);
            stringFieldStorage.stringField = field1;
            numericFieldStorage.numericField = field2;
        }

        if (!val.IsNull)
            storage.Total = storage.Total.IsNull ? val : storage.Total + val;
        else
            storage.Total = storage.Total.IsNull ? nullValue : (nullValue.IsNull ? storage.Total : storage.Total + nullValue);

        CallContext.SetData(dataName, storage);
        CallContext.SetData(field1Name, stringFieldStorage);
        CallContext.SetData(field2Name, numericFieldStorage);

        return storage.Total;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here's an image to make it a little more clear. (The columns of interest are stared. I would put in an image, but I don't have enough rep).

```
CUST_NO,JOB_NO,USR_ID,REF_NO,REF_DAT,ACT_DAT,HRS_WORKED,HOURS_QUOTED,BILL_FLG,BILL_HRS,EXCESS_HRS,running_total
ATA,1,AML,152364,2015-06-18,2015-06-16,0.25,12.00,Y,0.25,0.00,9.50
ATA,1,AMA,152367,2015-06-18,2015-06-18,0.25,12.00,Y,0.25,0.00,9.75
ATA,1,AML,152372,2015-06-18,2015-06-18,1.50,12.00,Y,1.50,0.00,11.25
ATA,1,AMA,152569,2015-06-22,2015-06-22,0.50,12.00,Y,0.50,0.00,11.75
ATA,1,AMA,152735,2015-06-25,2015-06-25,0.50,12.00,Y,0.25,0.25,12.25
**ATA**,**1**,AMA,153472,2015-07-14,2015-07-13,0.25,12.00,N,0.00,0.25,**12.50**
**ATA**,**2**,SCP,152097,2015-06-12,2015-06-10,0.50,3.00,Y,0.50,0.00,**13.00**
ATA,2,CTK,151923,2015-06-11,2015-06-11,0.75,3.00,Y,0.75,0.00,13.75
ATA,2,CTK,151998,2015-06-12,2015-06-12,0.75,3.00,Y,0.75,0.00,14.50
```

What I'm trying to do is change the C# code so that I can detect a change between CUST_NO or JOB_NO (if the CUST_NO is the same) and reset the running total column to 0 on the transition. Essentially, I want to do running totals for each of the JOB_NO for each CUST_NO. I realize this is a grouping function, but I'm using the CLR function because computing a running total efficiently is difficult in SQL and I'm going to be doing this for a table with 140,000+ records which is growing daily. Since I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, I do not get the Window ROWS functionality in 2012 so the only way I can get the reads down substantially enough to run a report on this data is to use a CLR function. The performance tests are explained in this article: [Best approaches for running totals – updated for SQL Server 2012](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I'm also open to suggestions for other implementations. I do have a cursor implementation currently, but again, it's quite slow. I've clocked it still executing over 30 seconds.

Comment: "Transition between field1 and field2". I don't know what you mean by that. Could you provide some sample data (preferably with the additional column of your expected running total)?

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll get to it tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do some kind of `GROUP BY` behavior, but  I am not entirely sure. A example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to re-write the CLR function to solve this problem you only need to partition your data properly.

`dbo.fn_RunningTotalBigInt(BILL_HRS, JOB_NO, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_NO,JOB_NO ORDER BY REF_DAT), null)`